# Encryption of files in chrome extension to store in Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

We are building a Chrome extension which allows users to generate audio files. We want the extension to encrypt, upload, and store the audio files in Firebase Storage. After that, we want to build a web app that our users can use to decrypt and read (play) those files without downloading those files on server side or on client side. After users decrypt the file and change it to its original form, they should also be able to download the file.

```
var file = ... // use the Blob or File API

//Enrypting file to store (in chrome extension)

ref.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
});
```

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: I understand you wish to create a Chrome extension which utilizes Cloud Storage for Firebase. I would like to assist, however, your question seems broad and vague. Please identify on the question what in particular you would like help with, what in particular is confusing when implementing file encryption?

Comment: Quick clarification, when mentioning Firebase Storage, I assume this is Firestore.

Comment: @KevinH I think firebase storage is this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage  It makes more sense to use firebase storage to store audio files than firestore which has a 1 MiB limit per document.